# How to check if my App is downloading a file from FTP

Tags: android

I am trying to download a file from FTP via my app. But neither of my toasts show. How can I check if I am connected and if the file is downloaded?

Code:

```
package no.kraftpriser.oversikt;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.SocketException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.commons.net.PrintCommandListener;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;

public class KraftpriserActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        FTPClient ftp;

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
        int duration2 = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;


        ftp = new FTPClient();
        ftp.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out)));

        try {
            int reply;
            String server = "62.97.235.213";
            int port = 21;
            ftp.connect(server, port);
            ftp.login("anonymous","nobody");
            ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            ftp.changeWorkingDirectory("/Fastpris");
            InputStream inStream = ftp.retrieveFileStream("2011.txt");


            CharSequence tilkoblet = "Connected!";

            Toast toastTilkoblet = Toast.makeText(context, tilkoblet, duration2);
            toastTilkoblet.show();

            reply = ftp.getReplyCode();

        } catch (SocketException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            if (ftp.isConnected()) {
                try {
                    ftp.disconnect();
                }
                catch (IOException f) {
                    //Do nothing
                }
            }
            CharSequence ikkeTikoblet = "Kunne ikke koble til server";
            Toast toastIkkeTilkoblet = Toast.makeText(context, ikkeTikoblet, duration);
            toastIkkeTilkoblet.show();
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "connected" toast wouldn't show until your transfer is complete since getFileAsStream will block until the transfer is completed. Additionally, you're just loading the file into an InputStream in the code above... you still need to write that input stream to a file if you want to persist it to your SD card or internal storage.

To be able to see the progress of the download, you'd need to do the actual download in a background thread (use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)). You can then post status updates back to the UI thread via the onProgressUpdate method.

Depending on the FTP client you're using, you can also probably check the return value from the connect and/or login method to see if each of those operations was successful.